# How to check if a user is already created, if not, create, else show an error message that a user is created Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a registration form in my front page and the goal is to check if a user is already created, if a user already exists, show an error message that a user is already created with given values.

My RegisterController create method now looks like this:

```
public function create(Request $request) {

    $create = User::create([
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'paypal_email' => $request['paypal_email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
    ]);

    if($create){
        Company::create(['user_id' => $create->id]);
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
}
```

How to check if a user is already created and if yes, show an error message?

Answer (score 2):

In your controller:

```
$request->validate([
    'email' => 'required|unique:database_table,column'
])->messages([
    'email.unique' => 'User has already been registered.',
]);
```

Then in your view:

```
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        {{ $error }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use firstOrCreate method.

Base on laravel documentation.

*The firstOrCreate method will attempt to locate a database record using the given column / value pairs. If the model can not be found in the database, a record will be inserted with the attributes from the first parameter, along with those in the optional second parameter.*

The first parameter should be the matching value pairs

e.g: ['email' => $request['email']]

The second paramater is the value that will inserted in your database

```
 $user = User::firstOrCreate(['email' => $request['email']]
 ,[
    'email' => $request['email'],
    'paypal_email' => $request['paypal_email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
]);

if ($user) {
 // records found
}
```

Read documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

Answer (score 1):

I would do a lot more before and after storing registration data in the database but for validation you can use Laravel validation. Here is a sample:

```
    public function create(Request $request) {


        $request->validate(    
           [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'paypal_email' => 'required|string|paypal_email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6'
           ]
        );

        $create = User::create([
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'paypal_email' => $request['paypal_email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password'])
        ]);

        if($create){
            Company::create(['user_id' => $create->id]);
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
    }
```

In the view the validation errors can be presented like

```
<!-- /resources/views/post/create.blade.php -->

<h1>Create Post</h1>

@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

<!-- Create Post Form -->
```

Reference: [Laravel 5.8 validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)